# Problems with contentPane in mx.flex.container eating mouse input

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm working on a game that uses mx canvases (each in their own mxml file) to wrap different aspects of the application.  So the UI is wrapped in one canvas, the main game screen in another, and so on.  I am having an issue where mouse input (specifically `MouseEvent.CLICK`, but it seems to apply to all mouse input) that I want to go to a movieClip in the `GameScreen.mxml` is being caught by an `mx.core.FlexSprite` object called "`contentPane`" that is a child of the `GameUI.mxml`.

This `contentPane` sprite doesn't exist when the `GameUI` object is instantiated, and in fact doesn't seem to exist until I set the text of some `textFields` contained by the `GameUI`.  These `textFields` do overlap the `movieClip` that I want to receive the mouse input, but the `textFields` themselves are set to `mouseEnabled = false`, and are not catching the mouse input.

None of my code is directly creating this `contentPane` sprite, and some elementary Googling tells me that this `contentPane` sprite is created by the `mx.flex.container` internally.  However, I can't seem to find any documentation on how this actually works, and what causes this sprite to be created.

This functionality has worked previously, and the only significant recent change I'm aware of is moving the swfs loaded into the `GameUI` into their own application domain to fix a namespace collision.  I'm entirely prepared to believe that is the issue.

Ideally, I'd like to know why this `contentPane` is suddenly catching mouse input.  Failing that, I'd at least like to find some documentation on how `contentPane` works, how I can manipulate it, and what causes its instantiation.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit:

I've done some additional digging and wanted to share what I've learned:

The `contentPane` variable is instantiated in `mx.core.container` objects for scrolling and clipping purposes.  If the content of an `mx.core.container` object exceeds the size of that object, the container will create a `contentPane` and move its contents into that pane.  However, if scrolling is disabled (`verticalScrollPolicy="off"` & `horizontalScrollPolicy="off"`) and clipping is disabled (`clipContent="false"`) then the container will not instantiate the `contentPane`.  This solved my specific problem as I did not need either scrolling or clipping behavior in this container.

I would still like to know if there's a way to disable mouse input for an `mx.core.container` `contentPane`.  It seems like there should be.